# How to Merge two DataTable with condition

Tags: vb.net, datatable, merge

I have 2 two DataTable dt_original and dt_updated. I want to merge them together
with a condition, how can I merge the row only if dt_updated have the same item_id with dt_orignal?

dt_original:-

```
item_id|item_name|qty|unitprice|col1|col2|col3|
===============================================
1      |apple    |5  |1.00     |xxx |xxx |xxx |
2      |orange   |10 |2.00     |xxx |xxx |xxx |
```

dt_updated:-

```
item_id|item_name|qty|
======================
1      |apple    |2  |
```

result that I want:-

```
item_id|item_name|qty|unitprice|col1|col2|col3|
===============================================
1      |apple    |2  |1.00     |xxx |xxx |xxx |
```

MyCode:

```
Dim dt_original As DataTable = Model_Query(str_tableControl1)
Dim dt_result As DataTable

dt_original.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dt_original.Columns("item_id")}
dt_updated.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dt_updated.Columns("item_id")}
dt_original.Merge(dt_updated)
dt_result = dt_original
```

MyResult:-

```
item_id|item_name|qty|unitprice|col1|col2|col3|
===============================================
1      |apple    |2  |1.00     |xxx |xxx |xxx |
2      |orange   |10 |2.00     |xxx |xxx |xxx |
```

So how to solve the problem?

Comment: So,in fact,you don't want to merge. you want the updated row with all the fields

Comment: @Pikoh so which function should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to update the quantity field? I would use LINQ and a loop:

```
Dim updatedRows = From rowOriginal In dt_original.AsEnumerable()
                  Join rowUpdated In dt_updated.AsEnumerable()
                  On rowOriginal.Field(Of Int32)("item_id") Equals rowUpdated.Field(Of Int32)("item_id")

Dim dt_result As DataTable =  dt_original.Clone() ' empty table, same columns 
For Each x In updatedRows
    dt_result.ImportRow(x.rowOriginal)
    dt_result.Rows(dt_result.Rows.Count-1).SetField("qty", x.rowUpdated.Field(of int32)("qty"))
Next
```

If you want to update the original table it's even easier:

```
For Each x In updatedRows
    x.rowOriginal.SetField("qty", x.rowUpdated.Field(of int32)("qty"))
Next
```

Comment: Although a good solution, using the DataRowExtention class is unecessary (SetField). When you do this it is creating unnecessary overhead especially when you don't need the library. What happens is the metadata loader will store this dll in memory adding no value. Also using SetField creates more unboxing problems. It internally invokes a generic method that validates the parameter and then uses a generic method to unbox the object inside the DataTable, there's no value to this at this point when you can directly change the value,  Thoughts @Tim Schmelter?

Comment: @Zaggler: if at all that's micro-optimizing. You are talking about the overhead of a `if (null == argumentValue)`-check, calling static extension methods or boxing/unboxing. Apart from the benefit of supported nullable columns(uses `DBNull.Value` then), the generic `Field`-method also adds safety: it checks if your type assumption is correct and can help to find bugs which is much more important for the developer and the customer than 1ms more or less.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Thanks for the feedback, good point about type assumption. Never had a straight answer before on these findings, thanks again for some insight.